# Add more data to SQL json Statement array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm converting a MySQL Query to json format on php, like this:

```
 $rfc = "R.F.C. ATP-880818-2P4";

$sql ="SELECT CONCAT(lov.ov,'-'," ; 
$sql .="lov.customerID,'-', pc.firstname, ' ', pc.lastname), suc.calle," ;
$sql .="CONCAT('Monto: $',po.total_paid)," ;
$sql .="CONCAT(suc.colonia,', C.P. ',suc.codigo_postal),suc.nombre, pc.email,pc.RFC,"; 
$sql .="CONCAT(pa.address1,'C.P. ',pa.postcode),pa.colony, pa.city,"; 
$sql .="CONCAT('Telefono: ',pa.phone), po.date_add from lista_ordenes_tarjeta lov ";
$sql .="INNER JOIN prstshp_customer pc ON  lov.customerID = pc.customerID ";
$sql .="INNER JOIN prstshp_orders po ON lov.id_order = po.id_order ";
$sql .="INNER JOIN sucursales suc on lov.sitio = suc.sitio ";
$sql .="INNER JOIN prstshp_address pa on pc.id_customer = pa.id_customer ";
$sql .="where carrier = 'E-PAQ' and liberacion = 1 limit 1";
$res = DB::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);



print_r(json_encode($res));
```

And this is the output:

```
{
    "CONCAT(lov.ov,'-',lov.customerID,'-', pc.firstname, ' ', pc.lastname)": "OV-2001028095-C000066524-Francisco jimenez  Medrano",
    "calle": "C. Lejos No. 3701 Int. Edificio 48",
    "CONCAT('Monto: $',po.total_paid)": "Monto: $289.360000",
    "CONCAT(suc.colonia,', C.P. ',suc.codigo_postal)": "Parque Ind. Las Americas, C.P. 35777",
    "nombre": "Torreon",
    "email": "mestizo_50@hotmail.com",
    "RFC": "XAXX010101000",
    "CONCAT(pa.address1,'C.P. ',pa.postcode)": "libertad 43B C.P. 45669",
    "colony": "San Juan de Ocotán",
    "city": "Zapopan",
    "CONCAT('Telefono: ',pa.phone)": "Telefono: 455124788",
    "date_add": "2021-08-22 15:38:29"
  }
]
```

I have another data that i need to add to the json but that its not retrieved from database.
Like RFC i have above and i need to put two more variables there. so it would be like this:

```
{
    "RFC: ATP-880818-2P4"
    "CONCAT(lov.ov,'-',lov.customerID,'-', pc.firstname, ' ', pc.lastname)": "OV-2001028095-C000066524-Francisco jimenez  Medrano",
    "calle": "C. Lejos No. 3701 Int. Edificio 48",
    "CONCAT('Monto: $',po.total_paid)": "Monto: $289.360000",
    "CONCAT(suc.colonia,', C.P. ',suc.codigo_postal)": "Parque Ind. Las Americas, C.P. 35777",
    "nombre": "Torreon",
    "email": "mestizo_50@hotmail.com",
    "RFC": "XAXX010101000",
    "CONCAT(pa.address1,'C.P. ',pa.postcode)": "libertad 43B C.P. 45669",
    "colony": "San Juan de Ocotán",
    "city": "Zapopan",
    "CONCAT('Telefono: ',pa.phone)": "Telefono: 455124788",
    "date_add": "2021-08-22 15:38:29"
  }
]
```

Is it possible in any way to do it?

Have tried to add as an array and insert the variable but it wont come correctly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yea! `$res['RFC'] = 'ATP-880818-2P4';` and then json_encode it

Comment: Or if `$res` is an object `$res->RFC = 'ATP-880818-2P4';`

Comment: The thing here is that $res is holding the query array. $res = DB::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql); Do i need to create another variable for the RFC?

Comment: I have tried this $json = array($rfc, $res);  but it only appends the RFC to the first array data and not the rest of them when its more than 1

Comment: You can try adding the text to the query, ie `SELECT 'R.F.C. ATP-880818-2P4' as 'RFC_VAR', CONCAT.....`

Comment: This will do the trick, Thanks a lot  @cOle2

Comment: Simply `print_r($res)` to work out what it actually looks like